# how to create react drag and drop UI builder with save each element position in db using React js

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, grapesjs

react drag an drop to create UI builder with save element data position in json or database.

prev i am using grapesjs but it will return html file instead of all components position, height, width in object form indivisual element.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.